Who is the angel of the Asian churches in Revelation that John was told to write to?
Since Paul was the head Apostle over the 7 churches in Asia, referred to in the first few chapters of Revelation, would he be considered to be the angel of those churches which Jesus told John to write to?

@Lesley   "Head apostle" was not the best choice of words.  The reason Paul was mentioned here is because he established those 7 churches in Asia, taught in them, and wrote his epistle in the New Testament to the Ephesians; Ephesus being the lead church of them.  Also he said in Romans 11:13:  "...I am the apostle of the Gentiles,..."

Appreciate the explanation, Joanne.  Will now delete my comment and thank you.

Whether Paul or (more likely) John was the earthly leader of the Asian churches, the Bible does not say.  In any case, this is not germane to the question at hand.
The facts that we can agree upon are these:

John was inspired to write a message, from Jesus, to each of the seven congregations as recorded in Rev 2 & 3.
each of these seven messages begins with Τῷ ἀγγέλῳ τῆς ἐν ... = "To the messenger in the church of ... write ...".  That is, each church appears to have had a messenger (the Greek word "angel" simply means "messenger."

That is, John writes to the person who would carry the message to each congregation.  The message would then be carried to each congregation and read to those present.  This conclusion is confirmed by the following:

the first part of the book of revelation is specifically addressed to the seven churches in the province in Asia, Rev 1:4.
In Rev 1:11, John is again instructed to write on a scroll and send messages to the seven churches.

Thus, each message to each church is addressed to the one who takes the message to each church.  Now, it is obvious that the one who takes a message is the messenger and thus, each message is addressed to the messenger (Greek is angelos) of each church.

@Lesley - The early church history (for what it is worth?) tells us that John had been the bishop in Ephesus and was the leader of the church in Asia.  When arrested in about AD 90 he sent letters to the churches.  However, even if this is not true, John was still instructed to write messages to the seven churches as recorded.

Thanks for the explanation, Dottard. I have removed my comment.

I was under the impression that when you write to someone in ancient times, their name is at the top of the scroll, and the mailman/messenger uses that name at the top to know who to deliver it to ("to the church in Ephesus"). Isn't it kinda weird to address your message to the postman ("to the postman bringing this to the church in Ephesus") instead of the one for whom the message is for? Is it possible "messenger" was a role or position in those churches, i.e. speaker/orator/preacher of God's message? After all, John the Baptist, Elijah, and Moses, were all referred to as "messengers".

What I mean to say is, perhaps "messenger" is more specifically those reading the letter aloud to the church, rather than those carrying the scroll to the church; assuming they may be different people.

@JaminGrey - that is possible.

At the outset, the idea that Paul would be the head Apostle over the 7 congregations in Asia needs to be put aside. He was dead long before the Apostle John wrote the vision he was given by "an angel" of Jesus Christ's. There is no precedence given to any of the 12 Apostles of the Lamb. Revelation 21:14 states that all 12 of the Apostles' names are inscribed in the heavenly New Jerusalem's foundations.
Now, the question asks "Who is the angel of the Asian churches"? This puts angel in the singular. In the book of the Revelation, many angels are detailed. One particular angel is identified as the one who relayed the visions of the entire book to John. This is the same angel who, at the end, warned John not to bow down to him in reverence (22:8-9).
The first vision is of the glorified Jesus Christ himself, who tells John to write a book, beginning with that first vision, continuing through to the last one. "Write the things which thou hast seen, and the things which are, and the things which shall be hereafter" (1:11). Then John is told that "the seven stars are the angels [plural] of the seven churches. And the seven candlesticks which thou sawest are the seven churches" (1:20).
Then Christ details what is worthy of his commendation, and what will bring his adverse judgment (if the various congregations do not repent of the latter). This comes first, before any of God's judgments on the earth and demonic forces are portrayed in the following visions. That is because

"Judgment must begin at the house of God, and if it first begin at us,
what will the end be of them that obey not the gospel of God?" 1 Peter
4:17 A.V.

This shows that there are seven specific angels responsible with regard to those seven particular groups in Asia, but the entire book of Revelation was to be copied to all congregations of Christians, so that they (and we) learn the principles contained throughout. Christ was not out to just judge those seven groups in Asia; end of story. As explained in this expository book:

"These churches cannot possibly represent one historical period after
another, so as to form as a whole the entirety of church history in
sequence from beginning to end. They cannot possibly follow one
another historically. Why not? Because all of these churches were
there then: the message was to their angel then. They were
contemporary then. All that was said was simultaneously true in
each of the seven cases...
Then the seven churches of Revelation 2 and 3 cannot be the one church
of that period, but must represent seven chosen out of that one unity.
But why? They were chosen out because their sevenfold condition in
fact signified all that could ever be right and all that could ever
be wrong in the ecclesia, or church, as a whole or in part at that
given period, and, in principle therefore, at any succeeding
period...
It follows that in principle, these churches were representative of
those conditions on which judgment was passed for the duration of the
age." The Revelation of Jesus Christ, John Metcalfe, pp. 59-60,
http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm 1998,


It is Revelation 21:14 which states that Jesus' twelve apostles' names were written in the foundations of the wall of the city.  Yes, even though the messages, which were sent by John to the angels of these 7 churches, was what was happening at that time, those messages would be true, if happening, for any Christian church of all time.

@Joanne  Have now corrected my typo. Well spotted!

The "angel" of these churches was not a human being. Rather, the author is speaking of a kind of angelic guardian such as is found in the Book of Daniel, where a powerful angelic being says to the prophet:
Daniel 10:13-21

"The prince of the kingdom of Persia stood in my way for twenty-one
days, until finally Michael, one of the chief princes, came to help
me. I left him there with the prince of the kingdom of Persia...   Soon I must fight the prince of Persia again. When I leave, the prince of Greece will come. [but] No one supports me against these except Michael, your prince."

Here, the being known today as the Archangel Michael is called the "chief prince." He was the patron or guardian angel of Israel. Similar, the churches of Asia had a patron angel, who is the speaker (or speakers) to John of Patmos as described in the OP.
Conclusion: Paul was not the angel spoken of as the angel of the churches of Asia. The author describes an actual angelic being (or beings) who was the guardian or patron of these churches.

The visions recorded by John were given to him a long, long, long, long time after Daniel was given his visions. Also, the Revelation is of Jesus Christ (read the opening sentence). John testifies to everything he saw - that is "the word of God and the testimony of Jesus Christ". Michael the archangel is nowhere mentioned. Where does it say in Revelation that the churches in Asia have a "patron angel"?

The best way is the traditional understanding of the angels being the proto-monarchial bishops of those churches.
For one, these angels are spoken in the singular, yet they are either praised or warned about the congregation's behavior.
Like the message for Ephesus:

1“To the angel of the church in Ephesus write: These are the words of Him who holds the seven stars in His right hand and walks among the seven golden lampstands. I know your deeds, your labor, and your perseverance. I know that you cannot tolerate those who are evil, and you have tested and exposed as liars those who falsely claim to be apostles. Without growing weary, you have persevered and endured many things for the sake of My name. But I have this against you: You have abandoned your first love. Therefore, keep in mind how far you have fallen. Repent and perform the deeds you did at first. But if you do not repent, I will come to you and remove your lampstand from its place. But you have this to your credit: You hate the works of the Nicolaitans, which I also hate. He who has an ear, let him hear what the Spirit says to the churches. To the one who overcomes, I will grant the right to eat from the tree of life in the Paradise of God.

It is tough to understand how said angels could be punished severely when said angels are in God's presence and have already decided for God.
The angel also gets held responsible for the sins of his community, a principle we see at work in exhortations to Christian leaders:

Attend to yourself and to your teaching; persevere in both tasks, for by doing so you will save both yourself and those who listen to you. (1 Timothy 4:16)


Not many of you should become teachers, my brothers, for you know that we who teach will be judged with greater strictness. (James 3:1)

These principles make it clear the angels of the churches are humans with an angelic role.

Firstly, each reference to "the angel of the church" in ch2 v1, v8, v12, v18, and ch3 v1, v7, and v14 is apparently referring to a different angel. One for each church.
The second point worth noting is that the messages that follow each introduction seem to make more sense as warnings and encouragements addressed to each church as a whole.
If a modern journalist published open letters to "Uncle Sam" and "John Bull", every reader would understand that these were not real individuals but personifications of the communities of the United States and Great Britain. I submit that we ought to read "angel of the church of Ephesus" and the rest in the same light. That is, they are not individual figures but personifications of their respective corporate bodies.

This answer is completely at variance with what is seen throughout the book  as to angelic activity.  No, the individual letters are addressed to angels in regard to the judgment that will be necessary if repentance is not forthcoming. But, mercifully, the letter is also sent to the churches themselves as a forewarning that, ahead of angelic judgment, the churches may take note and correct their behaviour and their attitude. See John Metcalfe's 'The Revelation of Jesus Christ'..

@NigelJ - can you provide a reference for your assertion, "the individual letters are addressed to angels in regard to the judgment that will be necessary if repentance is not forthcoming"?

@Dottard. Would these references suffice in regulars to your request to Nigel J? Rev.2:5,2:16,2:20-23& 3:3&5,3:19. Note that two of the seven churches (Smyrna and Philadelphia) did not receive a judgment type rebuke

@RHPclass79 - these all record judgement by Jesus and do not mention any angel of judgement.

@Dottard. I see your point.

@Dottard The letter is not written to the church. The letter is not written to a minister/servant/pastor/teacher/evangelist. The letter is written to an angel.

@NigelJ - that is untrue for two reasons - the letters are specifically written to the churches according to Rev 1:11, AND, does an angel of God need rebuke and warning as is contained in all seven letters about people?

I believe I have the picture now, thanks to all the comments.  These angels here were angelic beings who were the messengers of God to these churches, taking what John had seen, and told by Jesus to write it in a book and send it to these 7 Asian churches.

@Dottard I differ from you but shall comment no further. It is all expounded, very competently, in John Metcalfe's 650 page book on the subject, 'The Revelation of Jesus Christ'.

@NigelJ Obviously terms can have a symbolic meaning.
